# core data not being delete permanently through protocol function

Tags: ios, core-data, protocols, func, swift5

My code is trying to delete a element from a set via button. When the user presses the button the set is deleted from that page but if it is reloaded the code is still there. So it is not permanently deleted.  All I am doing is trying to delete a element from the core data set. I save the code in one class and iand display it through another. Link to git https://github.com/redrock34/core-Data-Delete/blob/master/photography%202.zip.

```
extension ViewController : datacollectionProfotocol {
 func deleteData(indx: Int) {

block.reloadData()

let date = users[indx]

users.remove(at: indx)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"atBATS = %@", date as CVarArg)

let result = try? context.fetch(request)
let resultData = result as! [NSManagedObject]

for object in resultData {
    context.delete(object)
}

do {
    try context.save()
    print(" saved!")
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}

}}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you actually trying to delete the item from core data or just remove it from the relationship?  Either way there should be no reason to start with a fetch.

Comment: Delete every trace of it from core data.

Comment: Assuming that the `Item` instances are referred to by your `User` entity and you are deleting the `User` entity (which this code doesn't do) then all you need to do is ensure that the relationship has a delete rule of "cascade" then when you delete the user all referenced `Item`s will also be deleted.

Comment: I added a photo above if that helps. I am trying to delete atBATS

Comment: I only want to delete one atBATS not the entire atBATS sets.

Comment: As the `atBATS` attribute is `String` a  `Date` predicate will never match any record. By the way you are strongly discouraged from ignoring errors in Core Data operations.

Comment: what do I replace date as CVarArg with?

Comment: Read the (archived but still relevant) [predicate programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) in the Apple documentation.